# checkbox array loop in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, foreach

I am receiving long string of checked html checkbox values (Request.Form["mylist"] return Value1,Value2,Value3....) on the form post in ASP.NET 2.0 page.

Now I simply want to loop these but I don't know what is the best practice to loop this array of string. I am trying to do something like this:

```
foreach (string Item in Request.Form["mylist"]){
  Response.Write(Request.Form["mylist"][Item] + "<hr>");
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to split the comma separated string. Try

```
string myList = Request.Form["myList"];
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(myList))
{
    Response.Write("Nothing selected.");
    return;
}
foreach (string Item in myList.split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
  Response.Write(item + "<hr>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do not use Split in Form values to prevent splitting values with commas.

```
string myList = Request.Form.GetValues("myList");
foreach (var Item in myList)
{
  Response.Write(item + "<hr>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete and debug DolceVita's answer, which has an important and correct point...

Given the following example HTML

```html
<p>Select numbers for a sum:</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="myList" value="1"/><label for="c1">1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="myList" value="2"/><label for="c2">2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="myList" value="3"/><label for="c3">3</label>
```

you can read selected checkboxes by

```
var sum = 0;
var selectedNumbers = Request.Form.GetValues("myList");

if (selectedNumbers != null)
{
    foreach (var selectedNumber in selectedNumbers)
    {
        // my example uses integers
        var number = int.Parse(selectedNumber);
        sum += number;
    }
}

Response.Write("<p>Sum: " + sum + "</p>");
```